# Can I specify whether to cap or overflow integers in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, integer, overflow

Can I chose whether to cap or overflow integer values in C/C++? Or are those compiled dependent?

Comment: *Is* there any compiler that "caps" overflows? I assume you mean it clamps to min or max.

Comment: @RogerRowland - that is correct, didn't expect to be unclear...

Comment: Some relevant info here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/199333/2065121

Comment: This is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370474/is-there-a-function-in-c-or-c-to-do-saturation-on-an-integer

Answer (score 3):

"Capping" as you refer to it is known as "saturation". It is common for Digital Signal Processors (DSP) to support saturation in hardware, but most microprocessors naturally overflow and wrap-around. Processors supporting DSP extensions such as MMX for example also support saturation.

Language support for saturation is normally by compiler extensions, intrinsics and libraries.  It would be possible in C++ perhaps to create a template class for saturating arithmetic types.

From my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370474/is-there-a-function-in-c-or-c-to-do-saturation-on-an-integer):

> [ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG14 N1169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1169.pdf) (*Programming languages - C -
>   Extensions to support embedded processors*) specifies a `_Sat` type
>   qualifier for saturating data types. I have never tried to use it in
>   any compiler, but it is included in the [GCC 4.x documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed_002dPoint.html).
>
> VC++ 2003 onward supports [MMX intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccky3awe%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) that allow saturating
>   arithmetic.

Note that on a processor without hardware support for saturating arithmetic, there is likely to be a performance hit in using it.

Comment: Software implementations of saturating arithmetic also make for hilarious graphs when the right university professor assigns it to students as an exercise. http://blog.regehr.org/archives/392

Answer (score 1):

"Overflowing" *unsigned* integer types is well-defined behavior that's dictated by the C and C++ standards. (To nitpickers: I know that it's not technically defined as overflow, but that's not the definition that fits what most people are actually interested in.)

Overflowing *signed* integer types, on the other hand, is [undefined behavior](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html).  Anything could happen.

Comment: So, let me get that straight, integer overflow is well-defined as undefined behavior? I get it, but one has to appreciate the logical paradox...

Comment: @user2341104: Note the distinction between *unsigned* and *signed* integer types.  It's well-defined for one, undefined for the other.

Comment: @user2341104 - No, it is defined for unsigned, undefined for signed. The "nitpicker" bit simply refers to the inaccuracy and common misuse of the term *overflow*.  If misuse of a word is common enough it often by *defacto* comes to mean what the users intend it to mean.

Answer (score 0):

As James already said it's signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. See here https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow for some ideas how to deal with it.