# Long to int truncation problem, truncating exceptions or handling error

Tags: c, integer, long-integer

Leetcode requires that the output of `-91283472332` be converted to int, and the output result is `-2147483648`. I use long to store the result, and then return int. Why is the result returned `-1089159116`

here's my code

```
int myAtoi(char * s){
    char *str = s;
    long n = 0;
    char *flag ;
    while(*str){
        if( * str =='-' || * str == '+')
        {
            flag = str++;
            continue;
        }
        if(*str<='9' && *str>='0')
        {
            n*=10;
            n+=(*str++)-48;
            continue;
        }
        if(*str>='A'&&*str<='z')
            break;
        
        ++str;

    }
    if(*flag == '-')
    {
        n-=(2*n);
    }
    return n;

}
```

So here's the description

- Input: s = "-91283472332"
- Output: -2147483648
- Explanation:

  - Step 1:

    ```
    "-91283472332" (no characters read because there is no leading whitespace)
     ^
    ```
  - Step 2:

    ```
    "-91283472332" ('-' is read, so the result should be negative)
      ^
    ```
  - Step 3:

    ```
    "-91283472332" ("91283472332" is read in)
                 ^
    ```

The parsed integer is -91283472332.
Since -91283472332 is less than the lower bound of the range [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1], the final result is clamped to -2<sup>31</sup> = -2147483648.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `-91283472332` is `0xFFFFFFEABF14C034` in hexadecimal, two's complement.

When it is trunctated to 32-bit long, the value is `0xBF14C034` and it means `-1089159116` when interpreted as two's complement.

You should add some conditional branch to return `-2147483648` when the value exceeds the limit.

Comment: Why -2147483648

Comment: Because the author of the problem required to return that?

Comment: How could that be, he's asking to implement an ATOL function, overflow truncation, how could that be a certain value

Comment: I understand that he is referring to the maximum value that can be represented by an overflow return int

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're doing [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/). Since it requires values outside the range to be **clamped** to the maximum values, A.K.A [saturated math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic), you'll need to check the value's range like this

```
if (n > INT_MAX)
    return INT_MAX;
else if (n < INT_MIN)
    return INT_MINT;
else
    return n;
```

It's similar to [`std::clamp(n, INT_MIN, INT_MAX)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) in C++

You can see that clearly in the requirements (emphasis mine):

> 5. If the integer is out of the 32-bit signed integer range [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup> - 1], then **clamp** the integer so that it remains in the range. Specifically, ***integers less than -2<sup>31</sup> should be clamped to -2<sup>31</sup>***, and ***integers greater than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 should be clamped to 2<sup>31</sup> - 1***.

Now compare that with the above if blocks

If you cast the value from 64 to 32-bit then it'll reduce the value modulo 2<sup>n</sup>:

- `-91283472332 % 2147483648 = -1089159116`,
- or in hex: `0xFFFFFFEABF14C034 & 0xFFFFFFFF = 0xBF14C034`

Saturation math is common in many areas like digital signal processing or computer graphics

- [is there a function in C or C++ to do "saturation" on an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4370474/995714)
- [How to do unsigned saturating addition in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121240/995714)